# Is it possible to use one phone number and redirect all calls to a VOIP server?

Tags: sip, voip

I am working on a project that records incoming phone calls. I am new to VOIP and SIP technology so everything is a bit vaque.

If i understand it correctly you have to use the SIP protocol to make phone calls from a 'hard phones' to a VOIP server? if so do i only need to buy one phone number at a SIP provider? and will every call be redirected to the VOIP server that handles the call?

I am asking this, because the project has to deal with a lot of incoming callers so i want to keep the costs as low as possible.